# how to count results to each array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi I'm currently developing a voting system using laravel. I want to attach a member count in each party. 
This is my code

```
$partylist = Partylist:all();
```

I want to achieve this on my blade :

```
{{$partylist->members}}
```

Comment: show your party and members model

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
{{$partylist->count()}}
```

or if you want to count the `members`:

```
{{$partylist->members->count()}}
```

or

`{{count($partylist->members)}}`

Answer (score 0):

If your `$partylist->members` is an array, use `sizeof()` function of PHP to get size of this. So you can use in blade as follows:

```
{{sizeof($partylist->members)}}
```

Hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it :

```
$partylist = Partylist::all();

foreach ($partylist as $pl) {
    echo $pl->members()->count();
}
```

Or counting related model

```
$partylist = Partylist::withCount('members')->all();

foreach ($partylist as $pl) {
    echo $pl->members_count;
}
```